# I'm benchmarking various DNS servers and one of the adresses shown seems like my router, how to check it?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, wireless-router

I'm using DNS Bench to test 10th's of DNS servers, and two addresses in the list appear to be from my router:

```
192.168.0.1         Non-routable local internet address
192.168.1.20        Non-routable local internet address
```

The  first one is actually the address of my router, and the second one is pointed by DNS Bench as being from my router too.

Now, after many tests these two addresses are always significantly faster. What I don't know is if the software is just connecting to my router, thus the lower latency, or if it is actually connecting to a DNS through my router, which is faster. If that's the case, I would like to know the real name and address of this fast DNS server, since software shows only the address of my router.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Router is appearing to be also a Caching DNS server (which is common these days )   once in the cache the subsequent queries (within a few  hours to few days normally  --depending on settings)  is only needing to ask the router not go through the whole song and  dance of contacting router then local ISP  then possibly  a more famous one like   google DNS.

and the .1 is likely the router and .20 the caching DNS server part form your router